# force:navigateToURL has started throwing some exception

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-components, blob.topdf, forcenavigatetourl

Earlier I was using force:navigateToURL to open blob file in new tab but suddenly it has started throwing the exception about `startsWith is not a function`.

> "Error in $A.getCallback() [c.startsWith is not a function] Callback
> failed: apex:...."

When I traversed back the error, I have found that exception is coming from navigation event manager js file when url event is fired.

> "TypeError: c.startsWith is not a function
> at Object.handle_force_navigateToURL (https://{domainname}/components/laf/navEventManager.js:23:128)
> at Object.b [as mb] (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs87/auraFW/javascript/MkNfdDJoMENESUp0R1E4b3hTRjFCUWI4T1Q3UVpoR0gtemxDX3B4aTM3bVEyNDQuMjAuMS0yLjQxLjQ/aura_prod.js:928:72)"

helper.js code to generate and open blob in new tab -

```
//cast to blob
const blob = new Blob([view], {
type: "application/pdf"
});

//Navigate to URL
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = filename+".pdf";
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
    "url": link 
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

What possible could be wrong here in my code or are there any alternatives to open blob pdf file in new tab?

P.S. I have already tried window.open() function and that is also not working for blob pdf files.